# How to create a bathymetric map with a irregular boundary from point data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation, 3d-analyst

I have a point shapefile, want to create a bathymetric map for a natural lake. I have tried 3D analyst and spatial analyst tools. They both create the bathymetric contour and surface raster based on the coordinates of the points I provided, in spite of the lake boundary. How to include the lake boundary in to the interpolation process.

I also have [seen people](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/interpolating_point_data.html) just clipped the raster file with the lake boundary, but I don't think it is correct.

Comment: Cant you add Points along the shoreline with depth values of zero?

Comment: hahah, that's brilliant

Comment: I am serious, should be pretty easy. You dont have to do it manually. For example with Feature vertices to point tool.

Answer (score 1):

Using the 3D Analyst Tools create a new TIN.  The points will be used as mass points.  The Z values from the point shapes, or from an attribute of your choice, will generate the bathymetic values.  Add the lake boundary polygon as a hard clip to restrict the TIN to the lake boundary.  Export to raster if necessary.